# What episodes of Shakugan no Shana S2 correspond to what volumes of the LN?

Tags: shakugan-no-shana

So, I am at around episode 20 of S1 of Shakugan no Shana.

The plan is to read two of the only 3 volumes TLed, in other words volume 7 and 8 and skip ahead somewhere to S2.

Then the plan is to get anime content for volume 9 and read the manga adaptation of the 10th volume (and the wiki summary for the non-TLed volumes of that).

Which episodes should I skip in S2 and which ones should I watch and what volumes do they correspond with?